# Are overwritten manifest activity declarations in multi flavor project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have a project that has multiple flavors, official docs says that manifest files are merged as one per build using dedicated manifest(from flavor directory) and default one. My scenario is that I have one Activity only into a flavor, and I'd suppose to declare it only in manifest for this flavor, but I get error `: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.flavor.name/com.default_project.name.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Is my approach correct or should I declare all activities in default Manifest file?

Comment: Are you sure you've `applicationId` and `package` defined with same name in `build.gradle` and `manifest` as well ?

Comment: @Shree Krishna `applicationId` is different because it must be different app per flavor, and if use `applicationId` there is no need for `package` I keep the same project directory tree for main project and flavors